# $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx\ $ converges, compute $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1}f(nx)dx$

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

Let $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R} \ $ be a continuous function.

Suppose $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx\ $ converges,

Compute: $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1}f(nx)dx.$$

**My attempt:**

I took $t=nx$, then $dt=n\ dx$, so we get:

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1}f(nx)dx=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{n}f(t)dt=0\cdot\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx=0.$$

Is it true? Am I missing something?

Comment: Looks ok to me.

Comment: As long as you know what you're doing at the last step, it looks good.

Comment: What do you mean? @OpenBall

Comment: @TrueTopologist **if** both limits exist (in this case they do) it implies limit of product is product of limits.

Comment: The only strange part is that $f$ is continuous. I do not see why this should be.

Comment: all you need is for $f$ to be $L^1$.

Comment: @AdamHughes yes I know this as a fact from a prior course.

Comment: TrueTopologist yes presumably so, I was just answering the question you asked @OpenBall. It wasn't clear from what you had written, hence his question.